# Change GPU quota on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cloud, gae-quotas

I am trying to change the quota for the number of GPUs I can use on a project on the Google Cloud Platform. Thing is I've made requests before on a different account and they all went through.

This is a brand new account about 5 days old and even though I've upgraded my billing the requests are still denied. I reached out for feedback and the response was

> Unfortunately, we are unable to grant your quota increase due to insufficient service usage history

I've reached out to their sales team but they haven't gotten back to me yet and I've tried putting in that I just created the account and upgraded billing in the justification for the request as mentioned [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/bNR6nYmo9Kg).

Does anyone know how to get requests to edit quotas on brand new accounts approved?

Comment: Did you try to re-summit your quotas increase request ? Did you answer to their email with the refusal? Did you open a ticket to the support?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere I did try to resubmit but it failed. They did respond though. The Quotas department said because the account is new that I don't have enough 'tenure' so to wait for a billing cycle to complete before trying to make the request again. Unfortunately I can't wait a month so I'm pending a response on that matter

Comment: Try to open a ticket to the support or to contact a Google Sales

Comment: On the [link](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/gce-discussion/bNR6nYmo9Kg) is the answer you are looking for: `As Our sales team state "service usage history and the availability of the resource that you are requesting" it depend on Service usage, In your case it's not possible since this is the first time for you, first did you  enable the billing in your project, then put a justification for the usage when requesting the GPU Quotas increase `Since your account is new, you need to wait.

Comment: In a second thought, maybe the best place to discuss this is with the agent who handled your quota request. Did you ask them if there's something you can do to get the GPU quota?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

After some chatting with the Google Cloud Platform Billing Support, the basic answer is no, there's no way to increase quotas on a new account.

The last bit of correspondence and essentially the official response:

> I was able to check with the downstream team the information |Support officer name here|
> provided you and before your projects can get their GPU quota
> increased it needs to accumulate more billing history. In my
> experience I would recommend you to try again and request the quota
> increase.

The issue is that new accounts don't have enough billing history or tenure to request quotas and one billing cycle has to pass in order for that information to be made available. I also asked if this is a policy that would change in the future to which the response was:

> Google has a very sensitive policy specifically regarding the quotas
> for GPU's, meaning this limitation on the product will continue to
> work this way since the only way to generate tenure on an account is
> by generating billing history.